# Enable EXIF support when running Wordpress Docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I’m trying to run a Wordpress site inside the [official Wordpress Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/).

The Wordpress site that I’ve built relies on using [`exif_read_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) to  extract meta information from photos. I understand that PHP needs to be configured with the `--with-exif` flag for this to work.

This is the *Configure Command* section of `<?php phpinfo() ?>`’s output when I’m running my site from the Docker container:

`'./configure' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d' '--disable-cgi' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-curl' '--with-libedit' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-apxs2' 'CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong '-fpic' '-fpie' '-O2'' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 '-Wl,--hash-style=both' '-pie'' 'CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong '-fpic' '-fpie' '-O2''`

How can I reconfigure PHP to have EXIF support enabled? I’d like to keep using the official Wordpress Docker container because it seems to be working really well otherwise.

My `docker-compose.yml` is here: https://github.com/quis/quis.cc/blob/d89efebefc20f688afbd70f8d7a58e35380581e9/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 15):

OK, I figured it out.

EXIF support can be enabled by running the `docker-php-ext-install exif`
command. This command only works when building the container.

I can’t modify the official container; the Docker way to do this (which is the part I didn’t understand) is to build my own container on top of the official one. Then when I build my own container I can run the command to enable EXIF support. Everything else is inherited from the official Wordpress container. So I made a file called `Dockerfile` containing this:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Then I ran this shell command to build an image from this file:
`docker build -t wordpress-exif .`

Then it’s just a case of pointing the Docker compose file at my custom
container, rather than the generic one. So in `docker-compose.yml` I changed `image: wordpress:latest` to `image: wordpress-exif`.

Comment: Adding `RUN docker-php-ext-install exif` to Dockerfile helped. In my case I'm using docker for laravel + vapor deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing and enabling exif like other answers, but not luck.

Finally, it worked by adding the package.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache php7-exif
```

I used `php:7.4-alpine`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 7.2+ the exif extension may already be installed but disabled. Add this line to Dockerfile to enable it:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-enable exif
```

Comment: `docker-php-ext-install` already invokes `docker-php-ext-enable`.
[source](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/21b6fadfaa4f19a430ecb52c1ad9437fb090718f/docker-php-ext-install#L104-L108)

Comment: This worked for me, I ran it on my apache container `docker-php-ext-install exif`. oh also I had to restart apache.